# Componente de Sketch para Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin-forms

Gostaria de saber se existe algum componente para Xamarin Forms que me permite desenhar em uma foto tirada pelo dispositivo ou que esteja na galeria.

Segue abaixo exemplos de como seria:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Dê uma olhada nesse componente:
https://components.xamarin.com/view/signature-pad
Você pode utilizar um SignaturePad e alterar a propriedade BackgroundImage.